# How do I track dataflow between bundles in OSGi

Tags: java, osgi

I need to check the data flow of a packet through the different bundles of back-end system in OSGi.

To a packet comes in through the 'gateway bundle' and then goes through several different bundles being processed. What I am supposed to do is make another bundle that knows "monitors" the data flow through these different bundles. Without the other bundles really knowing it's there.

How do I approach this?

Comment: Can you use Camel and some queues to route the messages between your components?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible except perhaps with some major rewriting at the bytecode level. In OSGi when you obtain a service or directly instantiate an object from another bundle, you have direct unfettered access to that object. There are no proxies between the bundles, and OSGi itself has no idea when a method invocation crosses a bundle boundary.

Perhaps it would be better to step back and question why you want to do this in the first place. What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: It's not that I want to do this, it's that I "have" to do this. It's a task I was given. I wanted to do it buy making a 'observer' bundle and make the other bundles notify the observer bundle whenever they do something of note. This would be MUCH easier to implement. But then they tell me "no, we do not want the backend to have any knowledge of the module you are supposed to make..".. The only solution I could think of was something like AOP than, but I'm not that familiar with AOP, and not even that familiar with OSGi either.. And as I understand AOP, I don't think it's the right solution

Comment: Okay so you need to help the customer to understand the problems with what they're trying to do, and work out what their underlying need is....

Answer (score 0):

You need to intercept the calls at the public API boundary?

One approach is the [interceptor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern). Typical ways of doing this in Java would be with AOP.

Are you already using Spring? If so, that has various flavours of AOP you could investigate.

I'm assuming that the code is doing direct method calls? If so, 123x's suggestion of using queues would require major refactoring of your code, so it is probably not a good short-term solution.

Comment: I'm only a small part of the team. The actual implementation hasn't even happened yet. I have to first do my data monitoring on a dummy system I have to make and gradually replace the dummy bundles with the real ones. I also have no idea what Spring is and only today was taught what OSGi actually is.. Also AOP was a new concept I heard today.

Comment: What OSGi container are you using? Which Java libraries do you use? You may already have the tools to build a solution at hand.

Answer (score 0):

If data flow goes via OSGi services registered by the other bundles, you can create a [java.lang.reflect.Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) object for every service and register these objects as OSGi services (with the same OBJECTCLASS and properties as original ones) with maximal [SERVICE_RANKING](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#SERVICE_RANKING). In this case, all call go to your services firstly and then you can forward them to original service.